# Merging different cucumber reports into one

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am using Selenium Grid and parallel_tests gem for paralleling my test suite.

How do I merge reports from each thread into one?

For example, I have several json reports.
Any suggestion in parser without stupid if-else statements is highly appreciated.

Note that, I can't do the following

```ruby
require 'json'
File.open("result.json", "w") {|f| f.write Dir.new(".").to_a.keep_if {|f| f =~ /^cuke\-\d?\.json$/ }.map {|f| JSON.parse File.read(f)}.flatten.to_json}
```

Because I may have **file1.feature:5** in one report and **file1.feature:10** in other report. So they have to be in one feature *object* inside summary report.